# Blender 2.8 display a subdivided view of the mesh, but without applying subdivision to the object

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface

When I press 3 on Maya it shows me a subdivided version of the mesh without subdividing the mesh, how can I achieve the same result in Blender 2.8? also, I should mention I'm emulating Keyboard Numpad because I don't have a big traditional keyboard.

Comment: Hello Keraera! You need exactly a shortcut to show base mesh without subdivision modifier?

Comment: Yes, I would like to see a smooth version of my mesh without subdividing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + n where n = a number so  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>2</kbd> means a subdiv modifier with 2 subdivisions

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> keeps the modifier but does not show the subdivisions.

Comment: only apply to the first subdivision modifier

Answer (score 1):

Each modifier has Show viewport property wich disable it in viewport.

[image: Show viewport]

A object may has more then one Subdivison modifier. It could be a python Operator to disable every Subdivison modifiers in viewport, then assign it to the desired shortcut.

Comment: thanks, I will try.